# How to setup ftp in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-ftpserver

Right now I am storing the uploaded images in local path, so I want to create one FTP server where I can store all my images so that others who are accessing my API can access the uploaded images also

I am not understanding where to start and how to create an FTP server 
my model:

```
class Resized_image(models.Model): image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "photos/%Y/%m/%d"), width_field='width', height_field='height', )
```

here i am specifying the local path to store uploaded images

I want to create an ftp server with uploads/ folder so that whatever the images I have uploaded using any server will be stored inside that uploads/ folder in ftp server

Comment: Why do you think you need an FTP server?

Comment: for example imagine all my code is in myproject folder so whenever i try to do POST request it will store image inside photos folder in myproject/ and i have pushed my code to git , so when other people are pulling and running the code locally and trying to access that image path,they willnot be able to access ,so i want to have one common server where i can post images

Comment: But FTP is not the answer for that. You could use something like Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: ok u mean to say i should use one of the clouds to store the images?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the need for storing files, and FTP Service.

From what you have mentioned you have a Django app, which you want to store images.

If you can upgrade/add storage to the server that you are currently using, you do not need an FTP Server.

If you can not add storage to the server where the FTP Server is running, then consider other network based storage. Cloud, AWS....

If you still can not find any storage - then reluctantly (and I mean really reluctantly) consider ftp.

Why ?

- It is a security nightmare.
- It will create more problems than it solves
- You should create users and password
- People will forget these, and you will spend your life resetting them
- all connections are easy to hack (un-encrypted communication channel to pass credentials)

For FTP - on Windows, it is built in to IIS. For Linux, you will need to add an FTP Server.